# No results in Browser with "Getting Started with the Closure Library"

Tags: google-closure-library

I am following the given steps to try,
"Getting Started with the Closure Library".

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted

Step 1: Download and Setup the Closure Library
Step 2: Create a JavaScript file that uses the Closure Library
Step 3: Create an HTML file
Step 4: Say Hello (with the created file) to the Closure Library.

Yet when using Chrome as the browser, on a PC, these steps yield a blank screen.

Is there some restriction with the example in Chrome? The example
was saved on C: Drive, in a directory for the closure-library,
C:\hw3_1\closure-library. Note here, this is not a homework problem,
yet a trial of the closure-library.

Right-clicking the screen, the following code is displayed:

[image: Sample Suggested Code for Google Closure]

As a test, when clicking on the hypertext, "closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"
the file opens in the browser.  Likewise, clicking on
the hypertext for "hello.js", this file also opens in the browser.

The example simply yields a blank screen.
Is there a solution available?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when I ran `hello.js` I got blank Chrome output (the same as the Original Poster) But I was fortunate enough to check the browser debug.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at` blah blah `closure-library/closure/goog/debug/error.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

If anyone else gets this look in `Chrome>More Tools>Developer Tools>Console` you will see the above type message alongside your "blank screen". See this link for details: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

The solution is to launch a single Chrome session using the following in Command Window (Run as Admin)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/repos
```

Of course these are my settings. Use Win Explorer to find your own chrome.exe and copy "Address as text" to a Notepad page. Assemble the remaining instruction - stating the folder where your `.js` & `.html` "Getting Started with the Closure Library" files are.

Paste the completed instruction string into the Command window. This should immediately launch a new Chrome session.

When the Chrome window launches it will have a gentle warning. Just type in your path & filename into the URL space.

Mine was `file:///C:/Users/david/source/repos/hello.html`

From here you can see the text `Hello world!` contained within the `sayHi()` function of `hello.js` showing in the HTML output.

This will let you move on with [Google Developer Getting Started with the Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted)